# drawable not showing dispite the code is correct

Tags: android, drawable

i have not been able to catch the issue. plz point me out if you find one. though the textview is handling the click, drawable are not null yet its not showing the image

```
strengthtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.strengthtv);
strengthtv.setOnClickListener(strengthivListener);

performancetv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.performancetv);
performancetv.setOnClickListener(performanceivListener);

shapetv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shapetv);
shapetv.setOnClickListener(shapeivListener);

...

switch (Prefs.PRODUCT) {
            case Prefs.APP_HC:
                Drawable strengthhc = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_goals_focus_bal_hc_2x_s);
                Drawable perfhc = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_goals_performance_hc_2);
                Drawable shapehc = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_goals_shape_hc_2x);

                Log.v("setgoals", " drawables------> " +  strengthhc + " -- "+ perfhc + " -- "+ shapehc);
                strengthtv.setCompoundDrawables(null, strengthhc, null, null);
                performancetv.setCompoundDrawables(null, perfhc, null, null);
                shapetv.setCompoundDrawables(null, shapehc, null, null);

                break;
            case Prefs.APP_BF:
                Drawable strengthbf = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_goals_focus_bal_bf_2x_s);
                Drawable perfbf = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_goals_performance_bf_2);
                Drawable shapebf = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_goals_shape_bf_2x);

                Log.v("setgoals", " drawables------> " +  strengthbf + " -- "+ perfbf + " -- "+ shapebf);
                strengthtv.setCompoundDrawables(null, strengthbf, null, null);
                performancetv.setCompoundDrawables(null, perfbf, null, null);
                shapetv.setCompoundDrawables(null, shapebf, null, null);

                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may want to use [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29). Or else you need to call `setBounds()` on the `Drawable` before setting it on the `TextView`

[From the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

> The Drawables must already have had setBounds(Rect) called.